# System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Lead.ConvertedContactId

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I'm writing a test class, but line 14, constantly throws an error when I'm trying to create test Lead objects. Here's my code and the error is the subject line of this post.

```
    @isTest (SeeAllData=false)
private class RL_Test_UpdateLeadType {

    @isTest static void test_method_one() {
        // Implement test code
        String query = 'Select Email, Lead_Type__c From Lead';
        List<String> emailDomains = new List<String> {'lpnt.net',
        'emhc.org',
        'ttuhsc.edu'};

        Lead l1 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = '', Company = 'Hospital A Company', FirstName = 'First Name A', LastName = 'Last Name A', Email = 'someone@lpnt.net');
        Lead l2 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = '', Company = 'Hospital B Company', FirstName = 'First Name B', LastName = 'Last Name B', Email = 'someone@emhc.net');
        Lead l3 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = '', Company = 'Hospital C Company', FirstName = 'First Name C', LastName = 'Last Name C', Email = 'someone@ttuhsc.net');
        Lead l4 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = '', Company = 'Hospital D Company', FirstName = 'First Name D', LastName = 'Last Name D', Email = 'someone@gmail.com');
        insert l1;
        insert l2;
        insert l3;
        insert l4;

        Test.startTest();
        RL_UpdateLeadType ult = new RL_UpdateLeadType();
        ult.query = query;
        Database.executeBatch(ult);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Verify data
        Integer j = 0;
        for(Integer i=0; i<emailDomains.size(); i++) {
            String str = '%' + emailDomains[i];
            j += [SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE Email LIKE :str];
        }
        Integer k = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE Lead_Type__c = 'Customer'];
        System.debug('===Comparing ' + j + ' with ' + k + '===');
        System.assertEquals(j, k);
    }
}
```

Comment: The field is not anywhere in your code. I bet that error is also giving you a class or trigger name, a line number, etc if you review the debug logs. All of that is extremely helpful and should tell you that it is not a problem in the test class above (directly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your batch needs a field added to the query. Does it help if you change line 1 to :

```
String query = 'Select Email, **ConvertedContactId**, Lead_Type__c From Lead';
```

Comment: You may have nailed it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked to get rid of my original error (why did I need that in my query?), but I'm now getting this error:
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

on the line:

`insert l1;`