# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object when creating Lead Object in Test Class

Tags: apex, leads, failing-tests

Getting this error when trying to run this test class:

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=false)
  private class RL_Test_UpdateLeadType {
    @isTest static void test_method_one() {
    // Implement test code
    String query = 'Select Id, Email, ConvertedContactId, Lead_Type__c From Lead';
    List<String> emailDomains = new List<String> {'lpnt.net',
    'emhc.org',
    'ttuhsc.edu'};

    Lead l1 = new Lead(Company = 'Hospital A Company', FirstName = 'First Name A', LastName = 'Last Name A', Email = 'someone@lpnt.net');
    Lead l2 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = null, Company = 'Hospital B Company', FirstName = 'First Name B', LastName = 'Last Name B', Email = 'someone@emhc.net');
    Lead l3 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = null, Company = 'Hospital C Company', FirstName = 'First Name C', LastName = 'Last Name C', Email = 'someone@ttuhsc.net');
    Lead l4 = new Lead(Lead_Type__c = null, Company = 'Hospital D Company', FirstName = 'First Name D', LastName = 'Last Name D', Email = 'someone@gmail.com');
    insert l1;
    //insert l2;
    //insert l3;
    //insert l4;

    Test.startTest();
    RL_UpdateLeadType ult = new RL_UpdateLeadType();
    ult.query = query;
    Database.executeBatch(ult);
    Test.stopTest();

    // Verify data
    Integer j = 0;
    for(Integer i=0; i<emailDomains.size(); i++) {
        String str = '%' + emailDomains[i];
        j += [SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE Email LIKE :str];
      }
    Integer k = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Lead WHERE Lead_Type__c = 'Customer'];
    System.debug('===Comparing ' + j + ' with ' + k + '===');
    System.assertEquals(j, k);
   }
}
```

Comment: At which line ?

Comment: @BrianMansfield Line 22. By eliminating every other line of code as a possible NPE, we know for a fact that this unit test is simply telling us that the batch class' code is bad.

Comment: On line 15: the `insert l1;` line. Not sure why it's complaining. I'm just creating a lead object.

Comment: do you have triggers on Lead - they could be throwing an NPE. The debug log would make this clear

Comment: Is there any trigger on lead object?? and ,If yes please share the code... The issue seems to be in trigger.

Comment: No, it's not a trigger. I wrote an Apex batch class and this is the test class for it.

Comment: @Slim - What class and line of code is the debug log telling you the error was trigger by? Troubleshooting this would be the exact same as troubleshooting your last question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93692/system-sobjectexception-sobject-row-was-retrieved-via-soql-without-querying-the

Comment: When I don't include the email address when creating the leads, I don't get this error. Any reason why I would get a null pointer by including the email address?